# Convert Int to binary in Assembly (pep8) - An elegant approach

Tags: assembly, binary, int

I am writing a program for one of my classes in assembly(pep8).  The program is supposed to take in an integer between -32,768 and 32,767, and output its binary equivalent.  The code below accomplishes the task except it prints the binary number backwards.

Is there an elegant way for me to print the binary number in the correct order (ie I DONT want to store every binary digit in a local variable and then print them in reverse order).

```
        BR main
int:             .EQUATE 0                ;local variable int
out:             .EQUATE 2                ;local variable out
index:           .EQUATE 4                ;local variable index
stack:           .EQUATE 6                ;local variable for dynamic memory allocation



main:            SUBSP       stack,i      ;allocate memmory
                 LDA         0,i          
                 STA         index,s      ;initialize index
                 DECI        int,s        ;get user input and store it in num 
while:           LDA         index,s      ;while (num <= 16)
                 CPA         16,i         ;
                 BRGE        endWhile     ;
                 ADDA        1,i          ;index++
                 STA         index,s      ;
                 LDA         int,s        ;
                 ANDA        0x0001,i     ;modulus 2 "%2"
                 STA         out,s        ;
                 DECO        out,s        ;output results 
                 LDA         int,s        ;
                 ASRA                     ;devide num by 2
                 STA         int,s        ;

                 BR          while        ;
endWhile:        ADDSP       stack,i      ;deallocate memmory
                 STOP
                 .END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar with this particular kind of assembly, but printing out a binary is relatively easy in all architectures if you shift values left, and check the carry flag `C`.

When you *shift* a register left, its most significant bit ends up in `C`. Now set another register to zero, and *rotate* it left immediately after shifting the source value left. The most significant bit of the original value is now in the least significant bit of the register:

```
Register   C   Value
--------   -   --------
00000000   x   11001010 // Initially
00000000   1   10010100 // After left-shifting the value
00000001   0   10010100 // After left-rotating the register
```

Output the register, set it back to zero, and continue on. This will output the bits in the correct order.

Note that this trick is available only to assembly programmers. It is inaccessible to C/C++ programmers, because the carry flag `C` is out of their reach.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. Is there any way for me to accomplish the same output with the approach i took (divide by 2 and store remainder)? (I saw the solution you suggest posted online but it felt a little like cheating since my original approach was completely different.)  Thanks for your help

Comment: @Azzi I do not think that using this approach would be cheating of some sort: this trick has been around well before "online" - for example, I learned it back in high school 25+ years ago on 6502, but it's been in wide use well before then. If you would like to use your method with minimum modifications, use `ANDA 0x8000,i` to single out the highest bit, and then rotate the value left two times to get the most-significant bit into the least significant position.

Comment: Do I have to rotate left twice b/c the first rotate puts the most significant bit in C?

Comment: @Azzi Yes, this is exactly why you need to rotate twice. If your CPU had an instruction that does not go through the carry bit `C` (I briefly checked online, and it does not look like pep-8 has such an instruction) you'd be able to rotate only once.